Does android support namespaces?
Does android support namespaces tried to search but i didn't find anything or maybe needs to edit the kernel
I don't know how can I try it.
Ahh stack overflow needs me to put 220 characters so let type anything just to pass this please stack overflow.
Edit : i was talking about android kernel i found that most kernels support it including mine you can now with root like this
sudo zcat /proc/config.gz | grep -i CONFIG_NAMESPACE

Please edit your question to explain, in detail, what it means to "support namespaces" and what that has to do with an OS kernel. There are many things in computer programming that involve "namespaces", and it is unclear which one of them is the one that you are referring to.

@CommonsWare Does android "kernel" support namespaces that somethings like unshare or newuidmap use.
